# Can't add the data to the struct

Tags: c

I am trying to deal with the struct in C language. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _list
{
    char *string;
    struct _list *next;
}LIST_T;

LIST_T* structHead;
LIST_T* structTail;
LIST_T* typedefHead;
LIST_T* typedefTail;
LIST_T* structList;
LIST_T* typedefList;

void typedefAndStructHandle(int choice,char* data);
void mystrdup(char* newString,char* originalString);

void typedefAndStructHandle(int choice,char* data)
    {
    if(choice==1)
    {
        structList=(LIST_T*) calloc(1,sizeof(LIST_T));
        if(structList==NULL)
        {
            printf("Error the program will terminate\n");
        }
        else
        {
            mystrdup(structList->string,data);
            printf("structList->string: %s\n",structList->string);
            if(structHead==NULL)
            {
                structHead=structList;
            }
            else
            {
                structTail->next=structList;
            }
            structTail=structList;
        }
    }
    else if(choice==2)
    {
        typedefList=(LIST_T*) calloc(1,sizeof(LIST_T));
        mystrdup(typedefList->string,data);

        if(typedefHead==NULL)
        {
            typedefHead=typedefList;
        }
        else
        {
            typedefTail->next=typedefList;
        }
        typedefTail=typedefList;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Something wrong with choice, try again\n");
    }
}

void mystrdup(char* newString,char* originalString)
{

    newString=malloc(strlen(originalString)+1);
    if(newString==NULL)
    {
        printf("newString, error allocation Terminate program\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(newString,originalString);

    }
}

int main()
{
    typedefAndStructHandle(1,"dummy");

}
```

This program will copy the word "dummy" and write it in Linked list. I created my own `strdup` called `mystrdup`. I think `mystrdup` has a problem. At the line

```
printf("structList->string: %s\n",structList->string);
```

it should print the word `structList->string: dummy` but my output is `structList->string: null` Does anyone has any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Your `mystrdup` function is flawed, it modifies the ***local*** variable `newString`. And as all local variables it will go out of scope and all changes to it will be lost when the function returns. There is a reason the normal `strdup` function *returns* the new string.

Answer (score 0):

mystrup needs to return the string, not take it as a parameter.

So, replace

```
 void mystrdup(char* newString,char* originalString)
```

with

```
 char* mystrdup(char* originalString)
```

and then declare `newString` locally and return it.

The caller needs to save the return value in a variable and ultimately call `free` on it

Comment: Alternatively, it could accept a `char** newString`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void mystrdup(char* newString, char* originalString)
```

You are reserving space for a local variable (`newString`) whose lifetime ends with the function, instead, return a pointer from the function:

```
char *mystrdup(char *originalString)
{
    char *newString = malloc(strlen(originalString) + 1);
    ...
    return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
void mystrdup(char* originalString)
{   
 structList->string = originalString;
}
```

No need or do not know what you want to do exactly with that function.
When you called this function de value of **strcpy** it was empty, so when you print gave you **NULL**